# NullPointerException during creating custom listview

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I have used following classes and xml to create a android custom listview.
**ArrayAdapterForCategory.java**

```
public class ArrayAdapterForCategory extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>{
    Context context;

    public ArrayAdapterForCategory(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtNumber;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_app_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textNumber);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.txtNumber.setText(rowItem.getNumber());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**RowItem.java**

```
public class RowItem {
    private String title;
    private String number;

    public RowItem(String title, String number) {

        this.title = title;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

**AppListActivityForTest.java**

```
public class AppListActivityForTest extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
     //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "my.json.feed.url";

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "categories";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "cat_title";
    private static final String TAG_NO = "total_apps";

    JSONArray categories = null;





ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.app_list_main);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

 // Creating new JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORY);

        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
          String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
          String number = c.getString(TAG_NO);


          RowItem item = new RowItem(title, number);
          rowItems.add(item);

        }

            // use your own layout
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
        ArrayAdapterForCategory adapter = new ArrayAdapterForCategory(this,
                R.layout.row_app_list, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

However, I have got a nullPointerException in onCreate method. I have done debugging which shows everything is okay till **rowItems.add(item);** . After that any problem is happened. But I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Provide complete logcat error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have just declared

> List< RowItem> rowItems;

you haven't initialized it.... So initialize it on onCreate() method..

```
rowItems = new List<RowItem>();
```

**List** is an **interface**. Interfaces cannot be instantiated. Only concrete types can be instantiated. You probably want to use an ArrayList, which is an implementation of the List interface.

```
rowItems= new ArrayList<RowItem>();
```

Comment: It shows an error saying "cannot instantiate the type List<RowItem>"

Comment: Thanks @Piyush Gupta, for your instant support with explanation

Comment: @CrazyLearner your always wel come!!

Answer (score 3):

You declare rowItems as a variable but never set it to an instance. So when you call .add(item) on it, it is set to null and you have the NPE.

Easy to fix:

```
List<RowItem> rowItems = new List<RowItem>();
```

...or so I thought. However, List is an interface (i.e. it contains unimplemented abstract methods) and interfaces cannot be instantiated. You need to use a concrete type that implements List such as ArrayList instead.

Comment: Yes, I have done what you say, but it shows an error saying,"cannot instantiate the type List<RowItem>"

Answer (score 3):

You do not initialise `rowItems` anywhere so it is null. Add the code before the `for` loop in `onCreate` or next to the variable declaration.

Also, change the `List` to `ArrayList`. `List` is an interface so cannot be instantiated.

```
ArrayList<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
```

Comment: It shows an error saying "cannot instantiate the type List<RowItem>"